# Can't implement pagination in firebase website

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

**Intenteded Functionality**

I would like to be able to have pagination on my website. The way it'd work is that users would view the first 10 questions on the main page, then they could click a button to flip to the next page to see the next 10 questions. They should also be able to go in the reverse direction as well.

**Method**

Presumably, it'd be best to have two parameters in my listenForQuestions function called pageNumber and pageLength. pageLnegth would be the number of questions to display on a given page and pageNumber would be the actual page number to go to.
I tried using startAt, but this doesn't takes an actual value to limit by rather than just by limiting to the first n results of the query as I would want.

```
import { getAuth } from '@firebase/auth';
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getFirestore, limit, onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  where,
  startAt,
  endAt
} from '@firebase/firestore';

export function listenForQuestions(options, callback) {
  let filters = [
        where('answerAccepted', '==', false),
        orderBy('bounty', 'desc'),
        orderBy('postedTimestamp', 'desc'),
    ];
     
  // filters.push(startAt(0), endAt(10)) // This doesn't seem to work???
  onSnapshot(
    query(collection(getFirestore(), 'questions'), ...filters),
    (snapshot) => {
      callback(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore pagination isn't based on offsets, but rather on a cursor - typically last item of the previous page. I recommend checking out the Firestore documentation on [pagination with cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) or some of the previous [questions on the pagination with firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20pagination).

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the response. But I've actually viewed that exact firebase documentation and it wasn't super helpful. As I said, it looks like "startAt()" takes in some value by which to order questions rather than being paginated in the normal sense. How would I actually go about paginating not based on the value of the query, but rather just based on the index of how it would be sorted normally?

Comment: You'll need to know an item to anchor on. For example, if you're paginating downwards, you take the last item of the first page and pass to to `startAfter`. This may not be how you're used to paginating results, but that's because Firebase has some performance guarantees it can't meet if you request by an offset. I recommend studying the example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) carefully, trying to make it work for you use-case, and posting another question with a repro if you get stuck.